# A keynav alternative not dependent on X11?

Tags: x11, console, software-rec, wayland, alternatives

Is there some alternative to `keynav` (a software that emulates mouse via keyboard) but without X11 dependencies?

Comment: I have not tried this software but I think warpd works on wayland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but in very early development: [tadeokondrak/waypoint](https://github.com/tadeokondrak/waypoint). It compiles and works, at least on my setup (using river).